# load more data into recycleview while scrolling

Tags: android, retrofit, onscrolllistener

First I read the data from server and put it into an `ArrayList`. Next, I put the `ArrayList` into an `Adapter` for a `RecyclerView`. When the user reaches the end, I want to send a request to server and get data for the `RecyclerView`. Now, I do it and it works. However, when I add more data, my `RecyclerView` moves to the first item and I must scroll down to see the new data...I want to add more data to the bottom of the `RecyclerView` without going back to the top.

This is my method to send the request to the server and fill my `ArrayList`:

```
private void getPosts(final Integer page, Integer limit) {
    getPosts(null, page, limit, new RemoteCallback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ResponseBody responseBody) {

            try {
                JSONArray data = new JSONArray(responseBody.string());
                if (data.length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finish", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                        posts = getPosts_(data);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            posts2.addAll(posts);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUnauthorized() {
            Log.e("data", "onUnauthorized");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailed(Throwable throwable) {
            Log.e("data", "onFailed");
        }
    });
}
```

And here is my `Activity`:

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static int ITEM_REQUEST_INITIAL_OFFSET = 1;
    private static final int ITEM_REQUEST_LIMIT = 10;
    private APIService mAPIService;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    AdapterContent item2RecyclerAdapter;
    private int mLoadedItems = 0;
    public static List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<Post>();
    List<Post> posts2 = new ArrayList<Post>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        mAPIService = ApiUtils.getAPIService();
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.item_progress_bar);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        getPosts(ITEM_REQUEST_INITIAL_OFFSET, ITEM_REQUEST_LIMIT);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity2.this);
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(MainActivity2.this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter) item2RecyclerAdapter = new AdapterContent(posts2);
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        getPosts(ITEM_REQUEST_INITIAL_OFFSET, 10);
                    }
                }, 1500);
                ITEM_REQUEST_INITIAL_OFFSET++;
            }
        });
    }
```

And here is my `Adapter` content:

```
public class AdapterContent extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterContent.SecondCollectionViewHolder> {
    private List<Post> posts;
    private Context context;
    private RemoteCallback<ResponseBody>remoteCallback;
    public SharedPreferences sp;
    public boolean state;


    public AdapterContent(List<Post> postList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.posts = postList;
        this.remoteCallback= remoteCallback;
    }

    @Override
    public AdapterContent.SecondCollectionViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View secondCollectionView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        return new SecondCollectionViewHolder(secondCollectionView);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final AdapterContent.SecondCollectionViewHolder secondHolder, final int position) {
        final Post post = posts.get(position);

        secondHolder.txt_postTitle.setText(post.getTitle());
        Log.i("mhs",post.getTitle());
    }
    public void add(Post r) {
        circleList.add(r);
        notifyItemInserted(posts.size() - 1);
    }

    public void addAll(ArrayList<Post> moveResults) {
        for (Post result : moveResults) {
            add(result);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return posts.size();
    }

    public class SecondCollectionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView txt_postTitle;
        public RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

        public SecondCollectionViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txt_postTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_postTitle);    
        }
    }
}
```

My question is how can I add data without going to first row in the `RecyclerView`?

Answer (score 0):

Lazy loading implementation with custom library or helper when load more received at the end of list

```
abstract class EndlessListener(private val carouselLayoutManager: CarouselLayoutManager) :
    RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

    private val visibleThreshold = 5
    private var currentPage = 0
    private var previousTotalItemCount = 0
    private var loading = true
    private var startingPageIndex = 0

    fun getLastVisibleItem(lastVisibleItemPositions: IntArray): Int {
        var maxSize = 0
        for (i in lastVisibleItemPositions.indices) {
            if (i == 0) {
                maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i]
            } else if (lastVisibleItemPositions[i] > maxSize) {
                maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i]
            }
        }
        return maxSize
    }

    override fun onScrolled(view: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        val lastVisibleItemPosition = (carouselLayoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition()
        val totalItemCount = carouselLayoutManager.itemCount

        if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount) {
            currentPage = startingPageIndex
            previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount
            if (totalItemCount == 0) {
                loading = true
            }
        }

        if (loading && totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount) {
            loading = false
            previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount
        }

        if (!loading && lastVisibleItemPosition + visibleThreshold > totalItemCount) {
            currentPage++
            onLoadMore(currentPage, totalItemCount, view)
            loading = true
        }
    }

    fun resetState() {
        this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex
        this.previousTotalItemCount = 0
        this.loading = true
    }

    abstract fun onLoadMore(page: Int, totalItemsCount: Int, view: RecyclerView)

}
```

And add a listener for change scroll position

```
 recycelerView.addOnScrollListener(object : EndlessListener(layoutManager) {
                override fun onLoadMore(page: Int, totalItemsCount: Int, view: RecyclerView) {

                }
            })
```